# How to print customized prefix in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

By default, log4j will print the class name as the prefix of log. Now my case is that I have multiple instances of class A in one JVM, and there's one log in this class. I'd like the log as following to allow me know which instance is printing this line of log ? How can I achieve this ?

```
2014-09-09 13:07:08,512 INFO com.myexample.A(id1)
2014-09-09 13:07:08,514 INFO com.myexample.A(id2)
```

Comment: One instance per thread or multiple instances per thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can not do it by settings in log4j.properties file. See possible variants [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

But you can solve the problem like this:

```
class A {
    Logger LOGGER;

    A(String id) {
        LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(getClass() + "(" + id + ")");
    }

    void myMethod() {
        LOGGER.info("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add desired ID to your log message:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
  int id = this.hashCode(); // Invoke ID getter method
  logger.debug( String.format("[ %d ] My log message with ID", id) );
}
```